# Click on cells and add display sum in another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range of values; I would like to click on a subset of this range and have the sum be displayed in another cell outside of the range.

Right now, I'm able to transfer the value of the clicked cell to another cell 
but I'm unable to display the summation of the values when I click multiple cells.

This is my current code; I also have the clicked cell turn yellow to indicate that it's been selected.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B7:B8")) Is Nothing Then
            Range("L7").Value = Selection.Value
        Target.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    End If
End sub
```

I'm wondering if I can apply a sum function to

```
Range("L7").Value = Selection.Value
```

Answer (score 1):

The status bar can be configured to show the Average, Count, Sum, etc of the selected cells. If you want to show it in a worksheet cell, try this

```
    Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

     If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1:B10")) Is Nothing Then
         Range("L7").Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Target)

     End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. If that solves your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour].